# How to print out the item of a list when its corresponding value in another list is the biggest?

Tags: python, list, max

If I have 2 lists:

```
values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
accuracies = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to return the value in values when its corresponding accuracy in accuracies is the biggest.
In this case, the result of value should be `'d'`, because its corresponding accuracy is `4`.
Is there a way to do it in python?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `values[np.argmax(accuracies)]` would work nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
In [5]: values[accuracies.index(max(accuracies))]
Out[5]: 'd'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by simply getting the max value the index of said value, then finding the equivalent in the values list

```
values[accuracies.index(max(accuracies))]
```

this returns in your case d